# How to fix the error type Item[] | undefined is not assignable to Item[] type using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am new to typescript and i am getting the error

"type Item[] | undefined is not assignable to Item[] type"

below is the code,

```
function Parent ({Items}: Props) {
    return (
        <Child subItems={Items.subItems}/> //error here
    );
}


function Child({subItems}: Item[]) {
    const sortedSubItems = subItems.sort((a: Item,b: Item) =>    b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt));

    return ( 
        <>
            {sortedSubItems.map((subItem: Item) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={subItem.id}>
                        <CardHeader>
                            {subItem.name}
                        </CardHeader>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

here subItems has structure like below,

```
const subItems = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'subitem-one',
        status: 'new',
        createdAt: '2020-08-13T16:32:10.000Z',
        orders: [
            {
                id: '1',
                title: 'subitem1-order-one',
                status: 'new',
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                title: 'subitem1-order-two',
                status: 'new',
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        id: '2',
        title: 'subitem-two',
        status: 'new',
        createdAt: '2020-08-16T12:02:06.000Z',
        orders: [
            {
                id: '2',
                title: 'subitem2-order-one',
                status: 'new',
            },
       ],
   },
]
```

and the Item type is like below,

```
export interface Item {
    id: string;
    createdAt: string;
    name?: string;
    orders?: Order[];
    subItems?: Item[];
}
```

could someone help me fix the error using typescript and react. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have an optional type operator(the question mark) on your `subItems` property, that indicates to Typescript that that property can be `undefined`. You will need to type the `subItems` prop for your Child component to reflect that, and handle it appropriately in the code:

```
interface ChildProps {
   subItems?: Item[]
}
function Child({subItems}: ChildProps) {
    const sortedSubItems = subItems ? subItems.sort((a: Item,b: Item) =>    b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt)) : [];

    return ( 
        <>
            {sortedSubItems.map((subItem: Item) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={subItem.id}>
                        <CardHeader>
                            {subItem.name}
                        </CardHeader>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case it can be a good idea to provide an empty array as default value to `subItems`:

```js
interface ChildProps {
  subItems: Item[]
}

function Child(props: ChildProps) {
    const { subItems = []} = props;
    const sortedSubItems = subItems.sort((a: Item,b: Item) =>    b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt));

    return ( 
        <>
            {sortedSubItems.map((subItem: Item) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={subItem.id}>
                        <CardHeader>
                            {subItem.name}
                        </CardHeader>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this issue because the `Child` component is `undefined` in some cases, in order to fix this you will need to handle these cases.

1. The sortedSubItems array may be undefined, so you can compute the outside the `Child` component .ie. in the `Parent` component and do a `&&` while passing it as a prop in the Child component.

```
function Parent ({Items}: Props) {
    const sortedSubItems = Items?.subItems?.sort((a: Item,b: Item) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt));
    return (
        <>
          {sortedSubItems && <Child sortedSubItems={sortedSubItems} />}
        </>
    );
}


function Child({sortedSubItems}: Item[]) {
 
    return ( 
        <>
            {sortedSubItems.map((subItem: Item) => {
                return (
                    <Card key={subItem.id}>
                        <CardHeader>
                            {subItem.name}
                        </CardHeader>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

2. You can keep the same code as you have, just change

```
const sortedSubItems = subItems.sort((a: Item,b: Item) =>  b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt)) ?? [];
```

This will conditionally choose the empty array